# VBA Code keeps crashing/never ending and Im not sure as to why

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I run my current VBA code it never ends and becomes non-responsive for both VBA and Excel.  I have tried implementing the application.screenupdating commands in my code as I saw this in another thread however the issue is still persisting.  Basically what my code does is it loops through all rows, looks in a cell in column 77, finds the specific date in that string, if it matches the current month and year and is from the 1st to the 11th, it will delete that row.

The second for loop goes through all rows again (Updated from previous removal of cells) and then deletes the row if column "CD" does not contain the key codes I am trying to keep. in the "if... And" statement.

This sheet has about 1800 rows and goes to column CL, so maybe just the mass amount of data is making it run slow but im not sure why it becomes unresponsive.  Any ideas on how to make the code run faster/actually complete and not become unresponsive would be greatly appreciated.  The worst thing is that I still have to add more conditions to this code later.

```
Sub PreApprove()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, day As Integer
Dim sentence As String, todaymonth As String, trimsentenceleft As Variant, monthtrim As Variant, todayyear As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


' get current date in the format: "MMM" and "YYYY"
todaymonth = Format(Date, "MMM")
todayyear = Format(Date, "YYYY")

For i = 2 To lastrow
'delete row if date is from current month 1st to current month 11th
For day = 1 To 11
        sentence = Trim(Cells(i, 77).Value)
        trimsentenceleft = Left(sentence, 20)
        monthtrim = Right(trimsentenceleft, 3)
        trimsentenceleft = Left(sentence, 23)
        daytrim = Right(trimsentenceleft, 2)
        trimsentenceleft = Left(sentence, 28)
        yeartrim = Right(trimsentenceleft, 4)
        If daytrim = day Then
            If yeartrim = todayyear Then
                If monthtrim = todaymonth Then
                    'MsgBox ("deleterow")
                    Cells(i, 77).EntireRow.Delete                                       
                    i = i - 1
                    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                End If
            End If
        End If
Next day
Next i

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow

        If Cells(i, "CD") <> "1E" And Cells(i, "CD") <> "1F" And Cells(i, "CD") <> "1E,1F" And Cells(i, "CD") <> "1G" Then
            Cells(i, "CD").EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - 1
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        End If

Next i
MsgBox ("All done")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For one, always loop backward when deleting rows

Comment: That actually just fixed the whole thing.  thank you @ShaiRado

Comment: Even better, use `Union` to build up a range to delete and then delete after looping.

Comment: @BigBen `Union` is my thing ;)

Comment: FYI you can use `Mid()` in one step instead of that combination of `Left()`+`Right()`...